# How to send a free message (like SMS) in android by using internet connection?

Tags: android

I have developed a small application to send SMS to another android device by means of SMSManager (Android Telephony).
While sending this app, device is using  cellular 3G connection even though Internet is enabled in the device.
Any thoughts on sending a free message (like SMS) in android by using internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for exactly SMS then you will have to try using some SMS gateway provider and look for their free packages.

If you are looking for something like SMS then you will have to develop a client-server application and install it on both ends of communication or use Google Cloud Messaging Service for Android to push data to the receiver device.

Comment: Will you please explain more about client-server communication?  I used SMSManager API, but it is not free as message is being sent through cellular data. By which android API, message will be sent to another device for free of cost ?

Comment: Its more like whatsapp, on both ends you will have your application listening for incoming messages. You probably will have to maintain the IPs of different users at some central location/database. When sender A sends message to user B you will get B's IP and send a packet to the program listening at B. For android APIs you should read about Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Apart from Whatsapp application like chatting ,just in normal sms sending application can Google Cloud Messaging be useful?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an app like wechat or kik or nimbuzz and you have to have your own ftp server (i mean host) to do that

i think it is not possible to send sms through the internet like a regular sms!!

Answer (score 0):

SMSmanager is locked to mobile web as it's governed by android telephony.

An alternative would be to use a different service along with a SIP provider such as pbxes to act as "faux-telephony".

Any attempt to continue using android telephony and activating over WiFi or any other connection will just transmit a command to send an SMS message over CDMA/gsm as SMS doesn't use actual mobile data.